# Akka / futures -- does Akka decide if it's "worth" using the current thread or the dispatcher?

Tags: java, akka, future, executorservice

I'm currently thinking about using Akka (Java API/libraries) to accomplish the task of creating several `Future`s and put them into a `BlockingQueue`. Now it might be that some tasks which are handled by Callables are fast/faster to run in the calling thread instead of creating a new Thread or waiting for a new Thread to become available. I think Akka is doing exactly this, for example if I'm running:

```
Future<String> f1 = future(new Callable<String>() {
                  public String call() {
                      return "Hello" + "World";
                  }
              });
```

It might be executed in the current thread which invokes future(Callable) or am I wrong? Maybe I'm wrong because I don't get how the dispatcher would decide if a new Thread is created or not.

Right now I'm just using an ExecutorService which uses other Threads, but since some tasks are really really fast they could as well be handled by the current Thread. But I'm using a `BlockingQueue<Future<Float>>` that's why I can't sometimes use `Future`s and sometimes not.

best regards,
Johannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always uses a thread from the supplied dispatcher, or the global default if no one is specified. To use the same thread you'd need to pass in a CallingThreadDispatcher, but then it will always be synchronous. There is no way at all that anyone except the programmer can decide whether a computation is cheap or not.

Comment: So can I somehow choose dynamically between a CallingThreadDispatcher and ehm... another one? I'm going to traverse a tree-structure and compute the descendant-or-self count for each node and some other things. Thus I assume on the first two or three levels it's worth to do the actual computation in parallel. But in some cases (level > 2 or at least on leaf nodes) it would be nice if I somehow could create futures which are executed in the current thread. As I can't mix Future and non Futures for the `BlockingQueue` I'm in a kind of "dilemma".

Comment: Make your computations inside your Callable, and reuse your computing thread with a DefaultCompletableFuture and complete it yourself?

Comment: I can't find the Java API / Javadoc reference for `DefaultCompletableFuture` or at all, only the tutorial :-/ Do you perhaps know if it's even doable in "pure" Java (1.7)? I don't think it's possible to create a Future without an ExecutorService, so I might have to use Akka, which I wanted to check out anyway ;-)

Comment: Read the ScalaDoc/the code for DefaultCompletableFuture in Akka